# PLSQL: How do I count the occurrences of a substring in all values in a column

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a table like this in an Oracle database:

| substring | string |
| --- | --- |
| abc | 123-def-abc |
| def | 123-def |
| ghi | 123-def-ghi |
| jkl | 123-456-jkl |
| mno | 123-456-jkl-mno |

I need to count the occurrences of each `substring` in all the rows of the `string` column. An example result would be:

| substring | string | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 123-def-abc | 1 |
| def | 123-def | 3 |
| ghi | 123-def-ghi | 1 |
| jkl | 123-456-jkl | 2 |
| mno | 123-456-jkl-mno | 1 |

How can I achieve this result?

Comment: What's your oracle version?

Comment: Version 20.2.0.175

Comment: 20.2.0.175 is not an oracle version. Check `select version_full from v$instance`

Comment: Is the number of substrings variable or will there always be the same 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few solutions:
[DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=bae151b300ceb8efcfd96d30f787ac49)

1. `cross apply` (or lateral or cross join):

```sql
select *
from t 
    cross apply(
       select count(*) cnt
       from t t2 
       where t2.string like '%'||t.substring||'%'
    ) a
order by substring;
```

2. subquery:

```sql
select
  t.*
  ,(
       select count(*) cnt
       from t t2 
       where t2.string like '%'||t.substring||'%'
   ) cnt
from t
order by substring;
```

3. `connect by`:

```sql
select 
   substring,string,count(*)
from (
  select
     connect_by_root substring as substring
    ,connect_by_root string    as string
  from t
  connect by nocycle
     level<=2
     and string like '%'||(prior t.substring)||'%'
)
group by substring,string
order by substring;
```

4. `model`:

```sql
select 
  substring,string,cnt
from t
model
  dimension by (substring,string)
  measures(0 as cnt,string as string2)
  rules(
    cnt[any,any] order by substring = count(*)[any,string like '%'||cv()||'%']
  )
order by substring;
```

5. xmlquery + xmlagg:

```sql
select--+ NO_XML_QUERY_REWRITE
  substring,string,
  xmlcast(
         xmlquery(
           'count($D/ROW/VAL[contains(., $X)])'
           passing
              xmlelement("ROW", (xmlagg(xmlelement(VAL, string)) over())) as d, 
              substring as x
           returning content) as number) as cnt
from t
order by substring;
```

Comment: Nice array of solutions

Answer (score 0):

This might be one option.

For sample data

```
SQL> with test (substring, string) as
  2    (select 'abc', '123-def-abc' from dual union all
  3     select 'def', '123-def'     from dual union all
  4     select 'ghi', '123-def-ghi' from dual union all
  5     select 'jkl', '123-456-jkl' from dual union all
  6     select 'mno', '123-456-jkl-mno' from dual
  7    ),
```

check whether `substring` exists in `string` (and use cross join, as you have to check *all combinations*)

```
  8  temp as
  9    (select a.substring,
 10            case when instr(b.string, a.substring) > 1 then 1 else 0 end cnt
 11     from test a cross join test b
 12  --   group by a.substring
 13    )
```

Finally, return the result by joining the "original" table and the `temp` CTE:

```
 14  select a.substring, a.string, sum(b.cnt) cnt
 15  from test a join temp b on a.substring = b.substring
 16  group by a.substring, a.string
 17  order by a.substring;

SUB STRING                 CNT
--- --------------- ----------
abc 123-def-abc              1
def 123-def                  3
ghi 123-def-ghi              1
jkl 123-456-jkl              2
mno 123-456-jkl-mno          1

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a CTE with 2 calls to the original tables, one using distinct to get the substrings and another to get all the occurrences of each string, cross-joined. We then use aggregation to count the number of occurrences of each match.

```
create table if not exists strings(
   substrin varchar(3),
   strin varchar(20)
   );
delete from strings;
insert into strings values('abc','123-def-abc');
insert into strings values('def','123-def');
insert into strings values('def','123-def');
insert into strings values('ghi','123-def-ghi');
insert into strings values('jkl','123-456-jkl');
insert into strings values('jkl','123-456-jkl');
insert into strings values('mno','123-456-jkl-mno');
with sss as
   ( select s1.substrin sb, s2.strin sg
   from (Select distinct substrin from strings ) s1,
   strings s2)
select
   sb 'substring',
   sg 'string',
   count(*) 'count'
from sss
where sg like concat('%',sb,'%')
group by sg,sb;
```

Note that this does not give the total number of lines which match the substring but the number of occurrences of each pair.